# Google Login API Error: invalid_request

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am trying to get user details from the default code given by google API... but its poping up an error,

error screen TEXT

**Error: invalid_request

400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_request

Application: sampleapp

You can email the developer of this application at: abc@gmail.com

Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.**

my request

```
openid.realm=
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
response_type=permission id_token
redirect_uri=storagerelay://http/127.0.0.1:51975?id=auth282512
ss_domain=http://127.0.0.1:51975
client_id=900278902057-ppqm358qrhki089danipqguj3i4ir70i.apps.googleusercontent.com
fetch_basic_profile=false
```

**Here is the code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Google+ JavaScript Quickstart</title>
  <!-- JavaScript specific to this application that is not related to API
     calls -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="900278902057-ppqm358qrhki089danipqguj3i4ir70i.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="gConnect">
    <div id="signin-button"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="authOps" style="display:none">
    <h2>User is now signed in to the app using Google+</h2>
    <button id="signOut" onclick="auth2.signOut()">Sign Out</button>
    <p>If the user chooses to disconnect, the app must delete all stored
    information retrieved from Google for the given user.</p>
    <button id="disconnect" >Disconnect your Google account from this app</button>

    <h2>User's profile information</h2>
    <div id="profile"></div>

    <h2>User's friends that are visible to this app</h2>
    <div id="visiblePeople"></div>

    <h2>Authentication Logs</h2>
    <pre id="authResult"></pre>
  </div>
  <div id="loaderror">
    This section will be hidden by jQuery. If you can see this message, you
    may be viewing the file rather than running a web server.<br />
    The sample must be run from http or https. See instructions at
    <a href="https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript">
    https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript</a>.
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auth2 = {};
var helper = (function() {
  return {
    /**
     * Hides the sign in button and starts the post-authorization operations.
     *
     * @param {Object} authResult An Object which contains the access token and
     *   other authentication information.
     */
    onSignInCallback: function(authResult) {
      $('#authResult').html('Auth Result:<br/>');
      for (var field in authResult) {
        $('#authResult').append(' ' + field + ': ' +
            authResult[field] + '<br/>');
      }
      if (authResult.isSignedIn.get()) {
        $('#authOps').show('slow');
        $('#gConnect').hide();
        helper.profile();
        helper.people();
      } else {
          if (authResult['error'] || authResult.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse() == null) {
            // There was an error, which means the user is not signed in.
            // As an example, you can handle by writing to the console:
            console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
          }
          $('#authResult').append('Logged out');
          $('#authOps').hide('slow');
          $('#gConnect').show();
      }

      console.log('authResult', authResult);
    },

    /**
     * Calls the OAuth2 endpoint to disconnect the app for the user.
     */
    disconnect: function() {
      // Revoke the access token.
      auth2.disconnect();
    },

    /**
     * Gets and renders the list of people visible to this app.
     */
    people: function() {
      gapi.client.plus.people.list({
        'userId': 'me',
        'collection': 'visible'
      }).then(function(res) {
        var people = res.result;
        $('#visiblePeople').empty();
        $('#visiblePeople').append('Number of people visible to this app: ' +
            people.totalItems + '<br/>');
        for (var personIndex in people.items) {
          person = people.items[personIndex];
          $('#visiblePeople').append('<img src="' + person.image.url + '">');
        }
      });
    },

    /**
     * Gets and renders the currently signed in user's profile data.
     */
    profile: function(){
      gapi.client.plus.people.get({
        'userId': 'me'
      }).then(function(res) {
        var profile = res.result;
        console.log(profile);
        $('#profile').empty();
        $('#profile').append(
            $('<p><img src=\"' + profile.image.url + '\"></p>'));
        $('#profile').append(
            $('<p>Hello ' + profile.displayName + '!<br />Tagline: ' +
            profile.tagline + '<br />About: ' + profile.aboutMe + '</p>'));
        if (profile.emails) {
          $('#profile').append('<br/>Emails: ');
          for (var i=0; i < profile.emails.length; i++){
            $('#profile').append(profile.emails[i].value).append(' ');
          }
          $('#profile').append('<br/>');
        }
        if (profile.cover && profile.coverPhoto) {
          $('#profile').append(
              $('<p><img src=\"' + profile.cover.coverPhoto.url + '\"></p>'));
        }
      }, function(err) {
        var error = err.result;
        $('#profile').empty();
        $('#profile').append(error.message);
      });
    }
  };
})();

/**
 * jQuery initialization
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#disconnect').click(helper.disconnect);
  $('#loaderror').hide();
});

/**
 * Handler for when the sign-in state changes.
 *
 * @param {boolean} isSignedIn The new signed in state.
 */
var updateSignIn = function() {
  console.log('update sign in state');
  if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
    console.log('signed in');
    helper.onSignInCallback(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance());
  }else{
    console.log('signed out');
    helper.onSignInCallback(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance());
  }
}

/**
 * This method sets up the sign-in listener after the client library loads.
 */
function startApp() {
  gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    gapi.client.load('plus','v1').then(function() {
      gapi.signin2.render('signin-button', {
          scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
          fetch_basic_profile: false });
      gapi.auth2.init({fetch_basic_profile: false,
          scope:'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'}).then(
            function (){
              console.log('init');
              auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
              auth2.isSignedIn.listen(updateSignIn);
              auth2.then(updateSignIn);
            });
    });
  });
}
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=startApp"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit the question and post the relevant code here, in the question itself. An external link to your complete application is against the site guidelines for several reasons.

Comment: but when i add its says your question is full of code, will try once again

Comment: Don't try to circumvent the guidelines, just try following them! Why do you think you need to post all your code? Don't you even know what parts of the code is failing to work?

Comment: code now added in edited version